# Selectpicker Is Not Working with Refresh with Drop-Down List

Tags: bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the below code, and my problem is that when I select the first time then the location list is not loading. When I select the second item then the first item in the sublist gets populated. If I select third then the second subitem gets populated.

I'm sure I'm making a silly mistake somewhere.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <label for="">SELECT CLIENT</label>
      <select type="search" id="myarray" class="select2-select req selectpicker form-control" data-required="1" data-max-options="1" data-live-search="true" multiple="" name="myarray[]" title="Select a Client">
        <?php echo $Clients; ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(".select2-select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getDataFromLocation",
      data: {
        type: 'select',
        selected: selected
      },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(output) {
        if (output) {
          //$('#append').append(output);
          $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
          $('#multiple').selectpicker('refresh').empty().append(output);
        }
      }
    });

  });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="multiple">LOCATION</label>
      <select id="multiple" class="form-control req selectpicker select2-select" data-required="1" name="Location[]" title="Select a Location" multiple></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we have some example data? what is <?php echo $Clients; ?> ?

Comment: My assumption would be that your `select` has `multiple` enabled. This means that when you ask for `$(this).val();` it will return an array, rather than a value. This would mean you're feeding the server some rather strange values.

Comment: Some example: Client 1, Client 2, Client 3, Client 4 and each client is having different different locations Location 1, Location A, etc.

Comment: We need an example request really. What data EXACTLY is sent to the server, and what data EXACTLY is sent back?Is each one as you expect? i.e. are you sending the value that you expect to be sending? are you receiving the values that you expect to be receiving?

Comment: Client 1
 Location A
 Location B
 Location C
Client 2
 Location 1
 Location 2
 Location 3
Client 3
 Location 12
 Location 34
 Location 45
Client 4
 Location A1
 Location B1
 Location C1
<?php echo $Clients; ?> -- It display Client x

Comment: I am getting list of client from server and storing in an array and then based on selected Client form that array I am fetching locations of that client in another array and then selecting third list based on Location selected.
My problem is when I select first client then result are not coming in next dropdown and when I select second client then subitem of firs client populated. I am thinking may be I need to increase one value in array I am not sure if that will work. I have given a try but not working.

Comment: Whatever it is, I'm fairly sure it's not in the code that you have provided. Certainly sounds like the issue is happening server side...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem has been resolved and the problem was refreshing the value from list.

```
$("#creatives").selectpicker('refresh').empty().append(output).selectpicker('refresh').trigger('change');
```

Used .trigger('change')
Thanks a lot for everyone's input here.

Answer (score 2):

This alone worked for me since "refresh" didn't seem to cause `selectpicker` to re-render:

```
$('#myselect').selectpicker('destroy');
$('#myselect').selectpicker('render');
```

Tested using Bootstrap 5, jQuery 3.6.0 and Bootstrap-select v1.14.0-beta3.

Source:

https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2456#issuecomment-1262477101

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Bootstrap 5 using Bootstrap-select v1.14.0-beta3.